# find elements with position:attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would try to find all "absolute" elements in my page; with jQuery I though it would be something like

```
$('[position="absolute"]')
```

but on ff 10.0.2 I cannot find an element...

Also, I cannot run the exaple code on http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ 
Is there something wrong on this syntax?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$('*').filter(function(){
   var position = $(this).css('position');
   return position === 'absolute';
});
```

You can't use attribute equals selector because because that selector would search elements with an attribute called position that equals absolute like this

```
 <div position="absolute">
```

but in your case position is a css property

Comment: Umm, onestly, I was more interested to know if there is something wrong in my syntax, than to explicity use filter...

Comment: @VitoDeTullio i updated my answer,position is a css property, not an attribute

Answer (score 11):

Building on Nicola's answer, you can also [extend jQuery's selector engine](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/).

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    absolute: function(el) {
        return $(el).css('position') === 'absolute';
    },
    relative: function (el) {
        return $(el).css('position') === 'relative';
    },
    static: function (el) {
        return $(el).css('position') === 'static';
    },
    fixed: function (el) {
        return $(el).css('position') === 'fixed';
    }
});
```

Then you can you do things like this.

> $(':absolute');
>
> $('div.sidebar:relative');

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("*[style*='position:absolute']").each (function () {
     alert($(this).html());
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/XRRbr/1/

More info: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: That can be possible but the code would be tricky. If the accepted answer has worked for you then that must be the valid answer. 

JFYI, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element